# semantics of __module__

Tags: python

I'm dynamically defining functions in a module and then updating the module's `__all__` and the function's `__name__` attribute to match the name it will have inside the module.  I was wondering if it is a good idea to update the function's `__module__` attribute as well to point to the module the function will reside.  The docs say `__module__` is:

> The name of the module the function was defined in, or None if unavailable.

The code that creates the function resides in a different module which is pretty much unrelated to the module where the function resides.  There is no reference to the function in this module.

I've done some poking around on the mailing list but I'm a bit confused as to what the semantics of `__module__` are and if I should set it to None or the module that the function resides or the module where the code resides that created the function.  Gonna leave it be for now but am interested to see if anyone knows the answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wouldn't do it. Importing functions from one module to another is a common occurrence. The `__module__` property is intended for retrieving the module where the function was defined, either to read the source code or sometimes to re-import it in a script. I don't see that it makes much difference whether the definition is via static code or dynamically: If someone wants to read your function's source code, they should look in the module that dynamically creates it.

You could take a look at [PEP 3130](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3130/). Although it was rejected, it might give you more insight into the purpose of `__module__` than the single-sentence description found everywhere else.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't have to worry about `__module__` usually, sometimes its used for dark magic or knowing where a function came (example) debugging from, but most of the time everyone ignores it. If your really worried set `__module__ = "dynamically_defined_function"` or something similar.

Comment: Well, this deep magic happens in several places you may care about (IIRC pickle uses it to locate classes when loading) and it's quite useful for debugging.

Comment: pickle doesn't happen as often as people think

Comment: Hence "*may* care". You are right that there are many situations where it does not matter. However, it's also possible you "need" the "right" value for it when you're not doing anything magic with it yourself.