# Python meaning of `array.__module__ = 'numpy'`

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I'm reading the source code of [numPy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/multiarray.py) what are we setting to value `numpy` to understand. some low-level features of arrays. What is `__module__` doing that it's a string?

```
arange.__module__ = 'numpy'
array.__module__ = 'numpy'
datetime_data.__module__ = 'numpy'
empty.__module__ = 'numpy'
frombuffer.__module__ = 'numpy'
fromfile.__module__ = 'numpy'
fromiter.__module__ = 'numpy'
```

Comment: Look up `__module__` on this page: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html

Comment: looking maybe here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113892/semantics-of-module

Comment: Looks like those lines are specifying that these compiled functions get identified with top level `numpy` as opposed to the file where they are defined. We don't normally use this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

That code has the result of making tools that parse the class metadata (notably including the documentation tool [Sphinx autodoc](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html)) report that the class is published by the main `numpy` module rather than the file that actually implements them. There are various reasons for doing this, but important ones are where either the class is implemented in C (in which case you don't get a module name by default) or where you want to otherwise hide the details of the implementation.